# Schedule TimerTask to run once

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc, jakarta-mail

I have been tasked to create an application that will send an email to a selection of recipients once every (n) minutes. The application in which this resides is structured in a way that it will reset itself by calling back to `<classname>.main(args)`whenever it is needed. My problem is, when I call to `<classname>.emailSending`, the application fires off 2 emails to each user immediately. The application does need to send an email at runtime, but it is only required to send a single email to each recipient.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
package database_administration;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

class EmailSending extends TimerTask
{
    public static FileInputStream propFile;
    static Connection conn = null;
    static Statement query = null;
    static String path;
    static Statement stmnt;
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            Date date = new Date();     
            SimpleDateFormat mailDate = new SimpleDateFormat();
            mailDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss");
            String mail = mailDate.format(date);
            propFile = new FileInputStream("config.ini");
            Properties config = new Properties(System.getProperties()); 
            config.load(propFile);
            String host = config.getProperty("host");
            String port = config.getProperty("port");
            path = config.getProperty("path");
            String DB_URL = config.getProperty("DB_URL");
            String USER = config.getProperty("USER");
            String PASS = config.getProperty("PASS");
            path = config.getProperty("path");
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

            String sender = config.getProperty("sender");
            Properties toRecipients = System.getProperties();
            Session current = Session.getDefaultInstance(toRecipients);
            toRecipients.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
            toRecipients.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", port);
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(current);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(sender));
            String[] recipients = config.getProperty("EmailList").split(";");
            for(int i=0;i<recipients.length;i++)
            {
                message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients[i].trim()));
                message.setSubject("Results of Audit Trail "+mail);
                message.setText(messageBody().toString());
                Transport.send(message);
            }
        }
        catch (MessagingException me)
        {
            System.out.println(me.getMessage());
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException fnf)
        {
            System.out.println(fnf.getMessage());
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
        }
        catch (SQLException sqle)
        {
            System.out.println(sqle.getMessage());
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException cnf)
        {
            System.out.println(cnf.getMessage());
        }
    }
    public static void emailSend(int control) throws IOException
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new EmailSending(), 0, control*60000);
    }
    private static StringBuilder messageBody() throws SQLException
    {
        stmnt = conn.createStatement();
        String SQL = "Select Action from Java_Test_AuditTrail";
        ResultSet rs1 = stmnt.executeQuery(SQL);
        rs1.last();
        int rowNumb = rs1.getRow();
        int list = 0;
        int delete = 0;
        int update = 0;
        int load = 0;
        int upload = 0;
        int display = 0;
        int add = 0;
        rs1.beforeFirst();
        rs1.next();
        int seeker=1;
        while(rs1.next()&&seeker<=rowNumb)
        {
            String actExecuted = rs1.getString("Action");
            if(actExecuted.equals("LIST"))
            {
                list++;
            }
            if(actExecuted.equals("DELETE"))
            {
                delete++;
            }
            if(actExecuted.equals("UPDATE"))
            {
                update++;
            }
            if(actExecuted.equals("RE-LOAD"))
            {
                load++;
            }
            if(actExecuted.equals("UPLOAD"))
            {
                upload++;
            }
            if(actExecuted.equals("DISPLAY AUDIT"))
            {
                display++;
            }
            if(actExecuted.equals("USER_CREATED"))
            {
                add++;
            }               
        }
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("Since Creation of the database, there have been: ["+list+"] List requests executed"+"\n");
        builder.append("\n");
        builder.append("Since Creation of the database, there have been: ["+delete+"] Delete requests executed"+"\n");
        builder.append("\n");
        builder.append("Since Creation of the database, there have been: ["+update+"] Update requests executed"+"\n");
        builder.append("\n");
        builder.append("Since Creation of the database, there have been: ["+load+"] Re-load requests executed"+"\n");
        builder.append("\n");
        builder.append("Since Creation of the database, there have been: ["+upload+"] Upload requests executed"+"\n");
        builder.append("\n");
        builder.append("Since Creation of the database, there have been: ["+display+"] Audit-Display requests executed"+"\n");
        builder.append("\n");
        builder.append("Since Creation of the database, there have been: ["+add+"] User-Creation requests executed"+"\n");
        return builder;
    }   
}
```

Comment: You should consider converting this to an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Presumably your problem is just that your `Task` seems to run twice. We don't care about your database config code or the creation of the message. Strip down your code to the minimal code that fails (i.e. runs twice)... and make your code a complete class, please, including declaration and imports. You may just find that this process enables you to solve it yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look at `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor` (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()). This is designed to do exactly what you want.

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
scheduledExecutor.schedule(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        /*
        send email
        */
    }
}, n, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

The runnable will execute every n minutes. If you want to stop the system, just send the `shutdown` command to the `scheduledExecutor`.

Comment: I don't suppose I can be cheeky and get you to use my code as a base? I'm still really new to Java =/

Comment: @BenignReaver: much better for you to try to implement his suggestion, and then come back with comment and your latest code attempt (as an edit to your question) if you're still having problems. If you don't try to push yourself to try new things on your own, how will you learn?